# C++ using GCOV/LCOV in a CMake project

Tags: cmake, gcov, lcov

I'm working in a C++ Project  with a structure similiar to the following:

```
---  /src
    |--comms
    |--utils
    |--interfaces
    …
    CMakeList.txt
--- /test
    |---test1/
              |--main.cpp
              |--CMakelists.txt

--CMakeLists.txt
```

I do need to control the coverage of my tests and for this purpose I use GCOV and LCOV in this way:

1. Enable coverage flags in all CMakeLists.txt to let the generation of .gcno files.

   ```
   SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O0 -Wall -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
   SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-g -O0 -Wall -W -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
   SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
   ```
2. Run test, generating the corresponding `.gcda` files.

   At this point, files gcno and gcda are located in the same directory as the corresponding `.o` file. I cannot move these files, because if I do it the report coverage generation doesn’t work.
3. From the directory in which files `.gcno` and `.gcda` are located I do the following:

   ```
   lcov –c –d . –o name.info
   ```
4. Generate the HTML report by using:

   ```
   genhtml  name.info.
   ```

When I compile my project, I have duplicated `.gcno` files due to the fact that when tests are compiled they need to recompile their dependencies (comms, utils, …) because I don't generate libraries for theses dependencies. I think there is no way to avoid that if I don't use libraries.

However when I try to generate the `index.html` (coverage report) for the global project, it doesn't work.

I use a Shell script that creates the same folder structure of  my project and copy each `.gcno` and `.gcda` to the corresponding directory. And I execute the commands `lcov` and `genhtml`, nevertheless the `index.html` *does not* include all project coverage.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

try to put `--ignore-errors` with genhtml command like that :

```
genhtml -o out name.info --ignore-errors source
```